# My Prestashop 1.5.6 freezes on last step install

Tags: php, mysql, installation, e-commerce, prestashop

I'm installing last version (1.5.6) of this awesome E-commerce CMS, never had this problem before.

All goes well, til the last step, when shop install is working (Step 6).

I searched the net about this issue, changed language, email. location, folder permissions... nothing works, keeps hanging on last step.

Here's an image of the issue:

[Prestashop issue image](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/uploads/monthly_10_2013/post-716917-0-41547600-1381721509.png)

Anyone can shed some light upon this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solved it, uploading everything again, btw it had also a permission issue in 'modules' folder, it had to be rwx-rwx-rwx in recursive mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where you live or how good your internet connection is but possibly 2 reason for that.
First you use a slow internet connection & Secondly you are a little impatient.
The last step is to install & create a huge number of tables, etc &  it takes time. Possibly you notice it when it goes to 12% of the install & you think it freezes but actually the Prestashop is working in the background establishing the tables that are needed for it work properly. It make take several ten minutes depending on the speed but whatever, do not cancel it. Let is work & hopefully you will be able to do it. I suggest you use a fast speed internet for this period at home or elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, i commented my own question some time ago, some files were missing during upload, and also 'modules' folder wasn't chmod 777.